# $> and $? in Perl

Tags: perl, special-characters

In Perl, do `$>` and `$?` have special meaning in the same way that `$_` and `@_` are "special"?

Answer (score 13):

Yes, there are many special variables whose name is a single punctuation character, including the scalar variable `>` (written `$>`) and the scalar variable `?` (written `$?`). They are documented in [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

[`$>`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%3e) is the process's effective user ID. It's “magical” in that assigning to it will change the EUID (if permitted).

[`$?`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%3f) contains the status of the last external process call. It's a little magical (e.g. you can only assign integers to it), but mainly several built-in constructs (such as backticks, i.e. `` `foo` ``) assign to it.

Comment: `$?` has plenty of magic. You can only assign integers between -1 and 65534 to it. You can set it inside an `END {}` block to change the exit status of your exiting program.

Comment: `$?` actually is magical, though I don't know to what end. (Oops, too slow!)